# Use UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute with UseStaticFiles when method = POST

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-middleware

I'm using `UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute` with `UseStaticFiles` to show an error page.

```cs
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Errors/{0}.html");
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

This works fine for GET requests. However for POST requests, this results in a 404. (I think; it goes to YARP's catch-all route.) I want to return nice error pages for POST requests as well, how can I achieve this? I could not find any settings on either middleware to achieve this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Scrubbing the request's method seems to work:

```cs
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Errors/{0}.html");
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            // Scrub http method when re-executing -- static files doesn't like POST.
            if (context.Features.Get<IStatusCodeReExecuteFeature>() is not null)
                context.Request.Method = "GET";
            await next();
        });
app.UseStaticFiles();
```